# Codename One BrowserComponent Not working

Tags: java, codenameone

I added the below code in `start()` method of my `Main class` but it's throwing error:

```
Form hi = new Form("Browser", new BorderLayout());
BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();
browser.setURL("https://www.codenameone.com/");
hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);
```

Errors

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found

[EDT] 0:0:0,571 - Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException - No toolkit found

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you put this code in the init() method and not in the start() method ?

Comment: It looks like your JVM is misconfigured. Notice we only support JDK 8 with Java FX (Oracle or ZuluFX etc) or JDK 11. Newer VMs might not work...

Comment: @Eric, I've edited my question was a mistake, the code is in start() method and not init() method.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, I use JDK 11. Talking of misconfigured JVM, I will uninstall JDK and reinstall then report back.

Comment: I've added screenshot of the full stack trace. I uninstalled and reinstalled JDK 11.0.5 and Apache NetBeans 11.2 but error still persist. I equally set JAVA_HOME environmental variable.

Comment: It's now working when I uninstalled CodenameOne Plugin for NetBeans and deleted .codenameone folder in the C:\Users\xxxxx\.

The next issue is that on Simulator the screen shakes and does not receive focus for all input fields on the web page but on android device I've tested on it's OK.

Comment: That might be related to scrollable mode, try to disable that

Comment: @ChibuikeMba A lot of people has the same exception with Java, try to google it. There is also a bug report on the OpenJDK: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8215352, but, as you can see, it's not considered a bug so it's not fixed. The code reported in the question, after adding `hi.show();`, works fine with Oracle Java 8 (I've just tested it). However, if you send an Android build or an iOS build, they should work fine.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, after setting scrollable to false the shaking stopped on Desktop skin but the website input fields still does not receive focus.

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani, the error message has been fixed, the issues now are shaking screen on Simulator(except Desktop skin) and input fields not receiving focus.

Comment: Are you using a simple test case like in your question, or is the BrowserComponent inserted in nested Containers?

Comment: Browser component on the simulator is a bit flaky and very sensitive to JDK/FX version.

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani, simple test, BrowserComponent directly added to Form.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, no problems I will be testing on device.